# how to keep hiding an element even when a new content is added using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote the following jquery to hide some elements :-

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('a.ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt:contains("question")').hide();
});
</script>
```

and it worked well when the page first load. but if a new content is being added using ajax then the above selector will not be able to hide it .. so can anyone adivce on this please ?
Thanks

Comment: Use the same piece of code in the ajax call back also.

Comment: Jquery selectors and its function wont behave like css.

Comment: but i do not own the ajax calls , it is system generated calls that update part of the web page when i click on a link

Comment: can you access the click event of the link?

Comment: where is the method called? If its called after the new content, and the content has "question" it should be called. can't tell much without a jsfiddle or link or something

Comment: @Carine but i think the script will not be able to wrap new content the have "question" text if the content is loaded in an ajax-based approach.. this what is happening. that why when the page first load the links will be hidden , but if i click on the "ajax based refresh" button the content with "question" will be shown.. not sure if i can use something such as ".live" to keep the script alive on newly added content...

Comment: well without seeing all the code, its hard to say, but if you want the original items to be hidden from the beginning, just set css to either display:none; or visibility: hidden; then show them when needed... sorry thats all i can say without seeing it

Comment: my script will hide them when the page first load. but if a new item is added to the page in an ajax-based approach, then the content which have "question" inside will not be hidden... i am trying to find a way to keep my script alive so it can understand newly added content...

Comment: What about `$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() { #doo some stuff}); ` It will be fired after every ajax call